# Strategies to shard local storage folders based on sequential key

Tags: file-storage

I am storing a large (~1M per year for ~30 years) amount of text files in file-based storage. Each file is named

```
FFFFFFFFFF-YY-SSSSSS.txt
```

where `FFFFFFFFFF` is a 10-digit filer key, `YY` is a 2-digit year, and `SSSSSS` is a 6-digit incrementing sequence for each filer in each year (so it starts at `000001`, etc.)

I wanted a strategy to make the individual folders a bit smaller (E.g., 10k or less). My first naive attempt at splitting the files apart was to use folders `YY/SSS`, where SSS was the last 3 digits of the key. Not surprisingly in hindsight, given the sequential nature of `SSSSSS`, my `001` folder ended up being very large (many filers only filing once per year), while I have many folders (e.g., `627`) with 1-2 text files in them.

**Question:** given `SSSSSS` is sequential per filer per year, and `FFFFFFFFFF` is very uneven by filer, is there any simple strategy that would improve upon my `YY/SSS` folder scheme to ensure no folders get larger than ~10k?

Comment: When a filer does a new filing, is there a reason to lookup the filename of their previous filing this year? Or is the new sequence number calculated based on other (external) information? Also, are there (other) search patterns going through a set of file names, or is access always based on an exact filename?

Comment: The new sequence number is determined by the central authority and is always +1. There's no reason to look up the previous filing on my side. Access is always exact filename; any other access patterns require external information (e.g., the master index of all filings with specific filing dates, etc.).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you have ~30 million files in total, that means you need ~3000 directories. Therefore just do `hash(filename) % 3000`.

Comment: Very interesting. So if I wanted to give myself room to grow (e.g., for the next 30 years), I could do `hash(filename) % 6000`, etc.?

Comment: YAGNI. Reshard in the future if/when you hit that point.

Comment: I assume `hash(filename)` is a placeholder for some language-independent algorithm, especially given Python 3 `hash` is randomly seeded by process. So I'd use, e.g., sha256 on the ascii-encoded string to ensure repeatability (or a faster non-cryptographic hash if the hashing time swamped the I/O time).

Comment: I never mentioned Python at all :)